# Integer coordinates to decimal google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have a database of trucks in usa . In the database the longitude and latitude are store in the form of integer . I have to map those coordinates on google map .

I searched on the internet and found out that it represent the degree and minute . I have these cooridinates

- Latitude => 324423
- Longitude => 883632

As per this [link](http://www.gps-forums.net/derive-latitude-longitude-integer-values-t33654.html)

i did this 32 is the degree and .4423 * 60 = 26.538 same goes with longitude when i place the coordinates on map its shows me position in China .

Answer (score 1):

At the first glance it looks like your Longitude is wrong. If you are in the US it must be something negative (due you are at the western hemisphere - west of Greenwich). If I just use the negative Longitude I get a location somewhere in Alabama. Does that makes sense for you? Please note that a W (for western) indicates a negative longitude while an S (south) indicates a negative latitude.

Comment: The state is AL and city is Cuba . How you did that ? in the database it has positive value

Comment: `Cuba, AL 36907, USA (32.4281952, -88.37642110000002)`,  Looks like you might have lost the sign (or the "W" hemisphere) when you saved the data in your database.  Where did those coordinates come from?

Comment: i got the excel file and it has two column one is for longitude and other is for latitude .

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Could it be that there is some metadata which tells you something about the hemispheres to use?

Comment: @geocodezip can you tell the process of finding these values . Thanks

Comment: 324423 => 32.4423 883632 => -88.3632; [Alabama 7, Cuba, AL 36907, USA (32.4414714, -88.36385129999996)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=32.4423,-88.3632&geocode=1)